# cant delete encrypted content

Tags: sql-server, encryption, reporting-services

I am trying to start my ssrs that I migrated from another box…
[image]

(I don’t mind losing the connection strings, I can insert the passwords later manually…) But, why isn’t it letting me to delete the encrypted bit?!

ps: worst case scenario I have a backup of all the folders and the .rdl but I do not want to do it manually is 10 different folders, and 25 reports in total…

Comment: Have you checked the link? Doesn't it answer your question? Also, if your question is about how to force it the error message provides a possible solution. Have you tried that?

Comment: This seems to be more about database administration than development (StackOverflow is a Q/A for programming related questions). Please try and find the most likely SE site, e.g. https://dba.stackexchange.com...